# JS Сравнение ключей и значений двух объектов

Tags: javascript, объекты

Только начал изучать js, есть непонимание как работать с объектами.

Есть массив, состоящий из объектов и ещё один объект. Ключи и там и там одинаковые. Как найти объекты в массиве со сходными значениями?

```
cars = [
      { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm5', year: 2014 },
      { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm4', year: 2013 },
      { brand: 'kia', model: 'sorento', year: 2014 },
      { brand: 'kia', model: 'rio', year: 2010 },
      { brand: 'kia', model: 'sportage', year: 2012 },
      { brand: 'bmw', model: 'mini', year: 2011 },
    ];

const findObj = { brand: 'bmw' };
```

Я могу получить список ключей в отдельно взятом объекте, но как сравнить ключи в разных объектах? Они не будут равны ведь?
Вроде как-то можно прикрутить reduce, но не понимаю с какой стороны подойти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если генерализовать задачу, как поиск по запросу любого количества ключей-значений, то получится как-то так:

```js
const cars = [
      { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm5', year: 2014 },
      { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm4', year: 2011 },
      { brand: 'kia', model: 'sorento', year: 2014 },
      { brand: 'kia', model: 'rio', year: 2010 },
      { brand: 'kia', model: 'sportage', year: 2012 },
      { brand: 'bmw', model: 'mini', year: 2011 },
    ];

const findObj = { brand: 'bmw', year: 2011 };
// Проверяем каждую машину
// на соответствие каждого ключа запроса
const result = cars.filter(car => 
  Object.keys(findObj).every(key => 
    car[key] === findObj[key])
);

console.log(result);
```

Или, более структурированно:

```js
const cars = [
  { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm5', year: 2014 },
  { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm4', year: 2011 },
  { brand: 'kia', model: 'sorento', year: 2014 },
  { brand: 'kia', model: 'rio', year: 2010 },
  { brand: 'kia', model: 'sportage', year: 2012 },
  { brand: 'bmw', model: 'mini', year: 2011 },
];

function search(list, query) {
  return list.filter(item => 
    Object.keys(query).every(key => 
      item[key] === query[key])
    );
}

console.log('All kia', search(cars, {brand: 'kia'}));
console.log('bmw mini', search(cars, {brand: 'bmw', model: 'mini'}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cars = [
  { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm5', year: 2014 },
  { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm4', year: 2013 },
  { brand: 'kia', model: 'sorento', year: 2014 },
  { brand: 'kia', model: 'rio', year: 2010 },
  { brand: 'kia', model: 'sportage', year: 2012 },
  { brand: 'bmw', model: 'mini', year: 2011 },
];

const findObj = { brand: 'bmw' };
cars.forEach(function(item) {
if (findObj.brand === item.brand ){
    console.log(item.model);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам подойдет:

- `filter` если нужно нати все вхождения. Эта функция возвращает масив елементов которые удовлетворяют условие
- `find` если нужно найти первое вхождение. Эта функция возвращает первый елемент масива которые удовлетворяет условие

```js
const cars = [
  { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm5', year: 2014 },
  { brand: 'bmw', model: 'm4', year: 2013 },
  { brand: 'kia', model: 'sorento', year: 2014 },
  { brand: 'kia', model: 'rio', year: 2010 },
  { brand: 'kia', model: 'sportage', year: 2012 },
  { brand: 'bmw', model: 'mini', year: 2011 },
];

const findObj = { brand: 'bmw' };

// если нужно первое вхождение
console.log(cars.find(car => car.brand === findObj.brand))
console.log('---')
// если нужны все вхождения
console.log(cars.filter(car => car.brand === findObj.brand))
```

Comment: А что делать, если искомые ключ и значение заранее не известны? Т.е. они могут меняться.